# First dependent data validation dropdowns work fine, subsequent return "Undefined"

Tags: javascript

The "Options" should all create a Data Validation dropdown based off of the "Category" input. ManualAutomatic and Option A work fine and return correct dropdowns. Options B thru E return a Data Validation dropdown that contains only "Undefined"

I am new to google scripting. I started with Learn Google Spreadsheet's tutorial and built from there. I apologize in advance if I am asking a question that is answered elsewhere.

```
var mainWsName = "Bid Sheet";
var nameData = "Data";
var Category = 1;
var ManualAutomatic = 2;
var OptionA = 3;
var OptionB = 4;
var OptionC = 5;
var OptionD = 6;
var OptionE = 7;


var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(nameData);
var manAutoOption = wsData.getRange(2, 1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();


function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if (wsName === mainWsName && c === Category && r > 3){
    OptionsValidation (val,r);
  } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === ManualAutomatic && r > 3){
    NothingScriptRemove (val,r);
  }//NothingScriptRemove is useless find a way to remove without breaking


}//end onEdit

function OptionsValidation (val,r){
     if(val === ""){ 
      ws.getRange(r,ManualAutomatic).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,ManualAutomatic).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionA).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionA).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionB).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionB).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionC).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionC).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionD).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionD).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionE).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionE).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r,ManualAutomatic).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionA).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionB).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionC).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionD).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,OptionE).clearContent();

      var filterOptions = manAutoOption.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,ManualAutomatic);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApply,cell);
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, Category).getValue();
      var filterOptions = manAutoOption.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue});
      var listToApplyA = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[2] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionA);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyA,cell);
      var listToApplyB = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[3] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionB);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyB,cell);
      var listToApplyC = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[4] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionC);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyC,cell);
      var listToApplyD = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[5] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionD);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyD,cell);
      var listToApplyE = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[6] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionE);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyE,cell);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer. A good night's sleep and a clear head make all the difference.
For anyone who stumbles on this looking for answers to similar issues...
This variable isn't pulling the correct data. Or more specifically it isn't pulling the right number of columns.

var manAutoOption = wsData.getRange(2, 1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();

"wsData.getLastRow()-1,3)" The last number is the number of columns that get pulled. Change that number to the number of columns you need to reference and everything else works great.